# Ejecutar procedimiento almacenado. Typescript, Nodejs, SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, nodejs, typescript, mssql

Estoy intentando ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado pero me arroja un error.EREQUEST.
No sé que podría estar mal.

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado que es dbo.obtenerUsuarios tal como se muestra en la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el error que obtengo es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Conexion:

```
export const obtenerConexionDB = async (): Promise<any> => {
   try {       
    
       const pool = await sql.connect(dbConfiguracion)
       return pool;
    
   } catch (err) {
       console.log("error conexión", JSON.stringify(err));
   }   
}
```

Servicio o data

```
export const psObtenerUsuario  = async () => {
const pool = await connection.obtenerConexionDB();
pool.connect(() => {
    try {
        const request = new sql.Request()
        const result = request.execute(constantes.procedimientosAlmacenados.obtenerUsuarios)
        return result
    } catch (error) {            
    }
})}
```

La conexión está bien, porque si ejecuto un request.query(), me retorna los resultados de la db. Agradezco algo de ayuda, no sé donde podría estar el error.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné:

const pool = await connection.obtenerConexionDB();
let result = await pool.request().execute(constantes.procedimientosAlmacenados.obtenerUsuarios);
//let result = await pool.request().query("select * from [User]");
console.log(result)

```
return result;
```